# send email daily from wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, email, cron

I customized a calendar plugin which shows today's birthdays and current months list of wedding anniversaries in the home page of the site. i wrote a code in that plguin's displaying page using wp_mail and mail will send. but this happens only when the site is visited. my code:

```
if($dat==date('Y-m-d'))/*$dat is the date of event from DB*/
 {
  if($eid!=''){ /*if recipient email id is not null*/
 if($se!=1)  /*if email is sending first time then($se=db column 'send'value) $se=0    otherwise it is 1*/
  {
    $to=$eid;
    $sub="Birthday Wishes";
    $msg='Happy Birthday '.$ev_title[$j];
    $headers= 'From:Mysite <noreply@mysite.com>' . "\r\n".'Content-type: text/html'; 
    $attachments=array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/plugins/spider-event-calendar/images/happybday.gif');
    $rx=wp_mail($to,$sub,$msg,$headers,$attachments);
    $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix.  "spidercalendar_event",array('send'=>1),array('id'=>$ev_id[$j]));/**/
    //echo "email send";
    }
  else{
  //echo "email already sent";
      }
    }
  }
```

i heard about wp_cron but when i searched in this forum about how to write cron in wordpress i saw an answer like

`Unfortunately the WordPress cron jobs are only triggered when your site is visited`
if it is true then how can i send emails daily even without visiting the webpage.is there any other way for this?

Comment: standard cron jobs are the best bet, do you have access to your servers command line? Or a gui that has a cron job section?

Comment: yeah i have access to my server through terminal..

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a regular cron job using your terminal via the following process after logging in;

access your con jobs list using;

`crontab -e`

There will likely be some lines in there already. Type <kbd>o</kbd> to enable editing of the file;

You can use the following website to generate the command for it to issue http://www.corntab.com/pages/crontab-gui.

as an example job I've got on my server;

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/www.mysite.com/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This job runs a php script every 5 minutes and prevents the site admin from receiving an email every time it runs. That's what `2>&1` does at the end of the line.

I'm actually a little unsure what `/usr/bin/php -q` and `>/dev/null` do, as I just copied them from another job that was already set up in that way. I'm fairly new to this via command line.

Once you're done editing the job, press <kbd>esc</kbd> and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>zz</kbd> to exit out of it. And you should be done.

I'd recommend using a test script that emails yourself, to make sure it works correctly first, then change it to use the script you're trying to run once you know it works.

I don't know if this process would be different for different server set ups, but it might be. This is just what I have to do for my server which runs CentOS with apache.

Comment: but sir how will i perform the above function using cron. i'm sorry if my doubt is a stupid question. i'm asking this because i'm a newbie in  wordpress and also have no previous experience in creating cron. plz help me

Comment: You would save that script as a stand alone page on your website - in my example I've called it `cron.php` in the root directory. You will need to add in more code to actually get the users birthdays as well as to satisfy your if statements. The page needs to work independently for it to work.

Comment: so let me tell what i understood so far  please correct me if i am wrong. "i should write the code which i posted in the question into a separate file 'exampl.php'in my site directory and then i need to login to my server through terminal and run the command that you posted with '@daily /path to exampl.php'."

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct to me. As I said in my answer the process to add the cron job might not be the same depending on server configurations so I can't guarantee that it will work for you too.

Comment: that i will google about the procedure. thanks Novocain88 for teaching me.. :) i will let you know after i figure out the problem.